# Moving a javascript character with the arrow keys

Tags: javascript, move, arrow-keys

I'm writing an RPG game in javascript, and I want my main character to move when youi press the arrow keys or the wasd keys. I have code to generate him, but how should I define his postion so he moves when the aforementioned keys are pressed?

```
function mainchar(){
    var mainchar = new Image();
    mainchar.src = /*I'll add this soon*/;
    mainchar.style.top = /*What should I put here?*/;
    mainchar.style.left = /*What should I put here?*/;
    mainchar.style.position = "absolute";
    document.body.appendChild( mainchar );
}
```

Comment: "What should I put here?", well that depends on where you wan't your character placed.

Comment: @Krister Should I put the starting position there and change it later?

Comment: Her's a representation, mainly running Scmiddty's code. I'll code some myself later. http://dl.dropbox.com/u/18785762/Rust/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Use: http://help.dottoro.com/ljaffqqe.php

To capture when the keyup / keydown using the correct key code.

Then set mainchar.style.top to where ever you want it to be moved to...

e.g.

1. Detect Key
2. When correct key is pressed
3. Updated mainchar.stlye.top

Comment: e.g. characters current top + 10? i dont know it depends how much youwant ot move him?